# does integrating apache with tomcat cause performance/memory gain?

Tags: apache-2.2, memory, tomcat

I am using tomcat standalone. Nowadays I see tomcat starts to use more memory than I expect. Serving static files from tomcat can be cause of this? Or can serving statics from apache cause better memory use.

Thx 
Enes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to share static content (HTML, images, CSS, PDFs, etc...) you can use Apache.
I think that it is more configurable and more robust and a lot faster than Tomcat.
You have to know that when you serve 100% static files with Apache, each httpd process will use around 2-3 megs of RAM.

Did you think to use a tiny fast server like [thttpd](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes !
Thanks to mod_jk (http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/index.html) you can tell to Apache to server some parts of you application that it would for sure serve better. I'm thinking about static content like pictures.
Here is a basic setup of the mod_jk connector  :

< VirtualHost *>

```
ServerName your name

DocumentRoot /home/tomcat/

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/application-error.log
TransferLog /var/log/apache2/app-access.log
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""

JkMount /* ajp13_worker
JkUnMount /img ajp13_worker
JkUnMount /css ajp13_worker
JkUnMount /js ajp13_worker
```

< /VirtualHost>

Notice that thanks to JkUnMount directive you tell to mod_jk to let Apache handle certain part of your application.Moreover, it's always better / simpler to type

yoursite.com than yoursite.com:8080